# Отправка данных формы без перезагрузки

Tags: php, ajax

Друзья, я не силен в PHP и Ajax, по этому прошу помощи. Имеется файл простой index.php, в нем имеется 2 формы. Как мне сначала скрыть вторую форму, а после отправки первой, без перезагрузки станицы показать вторую и скрыть первую, и в конце показать сообщение. Также когда отправляю данные в БД из второй формы (пароль) нужно записать его для ID того же пользователя (наверное брать из сессии).

Файл index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="one">
    <form action="save_user.php" method="post" id="form_one" >

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"  type="text"  >
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input  name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"  type="text" >

                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input  name="email" placeholder="Email"  type="text" >

                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" id="btn_1"><span>NEXT</span></button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="two">
    <form action="save_user.php" method="post" id="form_two" >

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="text"  >
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input  name="password" placeholder="Confirm password" type="text" >

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" id="btn_2"><span>NEXT</span></button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

файл обработчик формы save_user.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; if ($first_name == '') { unset($first_name);} }
if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; if ($last_name == '') { unset($last_name);} } 
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email=$_POST['email']; if ($email =='') { unset($email);} }
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }

if (empty($first_name) or empty($last_name) or empty($email)) 
{
exit ();
}

$first_name = stripslashes($first_name);
$first_name = htmlspecialchars($first_name);

$last_name = stripslashes($last_name);
$last_name = htmlspecialchars($last_name);

$email = stripslashes($email);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);

$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

$first_name = trim($first_name);
$last_name = trim($last_name);
$email = trim($email);
$password = trim($password);

include ("bd.php");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM cust WHERE first_name='$first_name'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
exit ();
}


$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO cust (first_name,last_name,email,password) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password')");

if ($result2=='TRUE')
{
header("Location: index.php"); 
exit();
}

else {
echo "Missing fields";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас очень сложный вопрос. Без смеха.
Вы предлагаете сделать за вас всю работу.
Вот если бы вы спросили "что мне нужно изучить чтобы сделать искомое?"
Тогда ответ: "изучайте jQuery, javascript"

Comment: Я понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы по второй части. Просто когда я отправляю вторую форму, у меня в базу пишется только пароль со своим ID.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. На форму. которую нужно скрыть вешаешь `dispay: none`, а на вторую форму `dispay: block`. При получении ответа через AJAX в success у первой формы меняешь display на `block`, а у второй на `none`.

P.s. скрывать и показывать формы можно через JQuery (`hide()` и `show()`)

Comment: Спасибо, с отправкой формы без перезагрузки разобрался. Подскажите, как мне сохранить сессию и при отправке второй формы записать пароль в БД пользователя с тем же ID? Сейчас у меня пароль записывается под новым ID...